# Upper bound for a continuous function g(x) on [0,1)

Tags: calculus, probability

Consider the function $\frac{1-F(x)}{1-x}$, where F is a CDF of a density f>0 on [0,1].

I want to argue that this function is bounded from above.

It is bounded by $1$ for $x>1$ and $x\leq 0$. It is continuous on $\left[0,1\right)$, so I think that if $lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{1-F(x)}{1-x}$ exists then the function is bounded from above. The problem is that the limit may not exist. Is it still possible to use L'Hospital rule to show that $lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-}\frac{1-F(x)}{1-x}=f(1)<\infty$?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous at $1$ then  the limit exists. But density functions are not continuous in general and that may behave very badly. In fact, strictly speaking,  $f(1)$ is not even a well defined number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $F(x)=1-\sqrt{1-x}$. That's a perfectly good CDF, but $\frac{1-F(x)}{1-x}\to+\infty$ for $x\to 1$. In particular the fraction is not bounded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is my claim correct when $f(1)<\infty$?.

Comment: @jjjant: No -- you can let $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 42 & \text{when }x=1 \\ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x}} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ and get the above $F$.

Comment: You're right. Thanks. I guess that for my argument to work I need to assume that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ in addition to assuming that $f(1)<\infty$.